show that $n^t=n,p^t=p,m^t=-q$
This is from humphreys Introduction to Lie Algebra and Representation theory textbook.
He defines $sp(2l,F)$ the symplectic algebra which consists of all endomorphisms $x$ of $V$ satisfying $f(x(v),w)=-f(v,x(w))$.
And then, he expressed $x$ in matrix form as $x=\begin{bmatrix}m & n\\p & q\end{bmatrix}$ where $m,n,p,q\in gl(l,f)$. For $x$ to be sympletic, $sx=-x^ts$ i.e $n^t=n,p^t=p,m^t=-q$.
Can anyone explain the last line to me? I did not get why : for $x$ to be sympletic, $sx=-x^ts$ i.e $n^t=n,p^t=p,m^t=-q$.
Note $s$ is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & I_l\\-I_l & 0\end{bmatrix}$ with the basis fixed. 

$s$ is the matrix representing the symplectic form $f$. In other words $f(v,w) = v^T s w$. So then $f(x(v),w) = -f(v,x(w))$ reads $(xv)^T s w = -v^T s (xw)$ in matrix terms. This can even be written as  $v^T (x^Ts) w = v^T (-sx) w$. Since this holds for all $v,w$ we can see this means $x^T s = -sx$ as required.
Note the same line of reasoning works for the orthogonal Lie algebras as well but a different $s$, representing a symmetric bilinear form instead of a symplectic one.

Oh thankyou! I still can't follow why $n^t=n$ and so on. Can you explain that?

@Raheel simply calculate $sx$ and $x^Ts$ (you are given $s,x$ as block matrices) and compare them

Yes, I got it. Thank you!
